# Chrome Extension Declare Permissions confusion

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, permissions

Simple extension to assign a keyboard shortcut to the high contrast setting so as to toggle it without going through menu's.  Problem:  The code below is producing this error

> ChromeSetting.get: You do not have permission to access the preference 'highContrast'. Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need.

The intro to this API https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/accessibilityFeatures#property-highContrast says to declare `accessibilityFeatures.modify` and `accessibilityFeatures.read` which I've done, however both these permissions are not on the declared permissions list https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions so I'm not sure where to go from here...

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "High Contrast Shortcut",
  "description": "Press Ctrl+Shift+Y to send an event.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "default_locale": "en",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["src/bg/background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "accessibilityFeatures.read",
    "accessibilityFeatures.modify"
  ],
  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y" },
      "description": "Send a 'toggle-feature' event to the extension"
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  if (command == "toggle-feature") {

    var value = chrome.accessibilityFeatures.highContrast.get({'incognito': false}, function (callback) {
      console.log(callback);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"accessibilityFeatures.read"` and `"accessibilityFeatures.modify"` are currently only supported in Chrome OS, not on other operating systems, as seen in https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/7c61e0145f3e598ae7a9ac69159234d6ec7f6008/chrome/common/extensions/api/_permission_features.json:

```
  "accessibilityFeatures.modify": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "extension_types": ["extension", "platform_app"],
    "platforms": ["chromeos"]
  },
  "accessibilityFeatures.read": {
    "channel": "stable",
    "extension_types": ["extension", "platform_app"],
    "platforms": ["chromeos"]
  },
```

Comment: How to properly raise bugs about documentation? Because that's a serious lapse.

Comment: @Xan On the issue tracker, like this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=420014

Comment: I am on a chromebook so editing the setting should work for me, but where do I add this code?  To the permissions tab?

Comment: @JacobEdward If you're on a Chromebook, then setting these permissions (as you did in the question) should work. Is your Chrombook running Chrome OS 37 or higher?

Comment: I've got version 36 apparently, are you saying being able to custom script the settings was a very recent feature?

Comment: @JacobEdward This API was added in Chrome 35, but only enabled on the dev channel back then. `chrome.accessibilityFeatures` has been enabled on the stable channel as well since Chrome 37, which was released last month. You should be able to update your OS if you're still at 36... If that does not work, try [switching to a different channel](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1086915). But I really believe that you should be at version 37 now. Have you already tried restarting your Chromebook?

Comment: Ok, so I wrote the extension, it wasn't behaving properly for about 20 minutes (basic stuff like conditionals not executing properly), then it started working...  After a while I needed to restart my machine, and now it's not working again... do you know if there are problems with this API?

Comment: @JacobEdward No I don't, especially with a description as vague as "it is not working" ;) Could you create a minimal example (code + instructions) that shows how to reproduce your problem and create a ticket at https://crbug.com/new? If you don't want to report it yourself, feel free to mail the details to me, then I will make sure that the bug report gets to the right people.

Comment: http://www.codeshare.io/3fpYs With the same manifest.json, this worked for maybe a half hour, then stopped working after I restarted my computer, nothing in my code was changed

Comment: @JacobEdward "stopped working" doesn't tell me anything. Please elaborate on what you expect, and what happened instead.

Comment: I expect the key command to toggle the setting, if it's on, turn it off, if it's off, turn it on.  This worked exactly as I expected it to for that brief period of time, now it's not toggling the setting.  The code I shared is very very basic, and yet isn't working consistently.

Comment: @JacobEdward Sounds like a quota restriction or a bug. Does the console contain any errors? Add `console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);` in the callbacks to see whether any error occurs. If that doesn't provide any useful information, could you create an issue at https://crbug.com/new?

Comment: Ok, I'll submit an issue report, apparently the keyboard command isn't being registered since the console isn't logging anything, even a regular string, but I know the commands API is working since I'm using it in another extension (already made sure the API is being written correctly by copy and paste from the functioning extension), so I haven't got a clue what it might be, thanks for the help